# Batch Delete Records in Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop

I have a table in my DB which only gets records deleted when a particular report runs and can grow fairly large in those periods.  I am implementing a batch delete for when the report does run.  Just wanted to get an opinion on the route to go.

```
While Exists (select top (1) StoreNbr from #Test WHERE DATEDIFF(dd, LogDate, GETDATE()) >= 60)
Begin
          delete top (5000) from #Test WHERE DATEDIFF(dd, LogDate, GETDATE()) >= 60
End
```

1. Should I use a waitfor delay within the loop, does this have any practical benefits?
2. Should I disable the indexes on the table previous to performing the deletes and re-enable them once complete?

Comment: Please be sure to mention which dialect of SQL you're working with.  I've guessed MS SQL Server from the syntax, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

How about using stored procedure? I used it in the past. Include delete and select statement in the stored procedure. Make your report execute the stored procedure and your report will get info and delete records in one step.

Comment: The report itself is a stored procedure and happens to clean out this table as a last step but was causing the SSIS package to fail due to huge amount of data being deleted with : 
Delete from table1 where date < @Date.  I'm just hoping for some input on the best way to batch delete around 10 million records with indexes on multiple columns.

Comment: Try drop indexes before delete then recreate index after delete is complete.